# Showing that a real function is convex

Tags: analysis

How can I show that if $\varphi$ is a real function such that $$\varphi \left(\int_0^1 f\right)\leqslant \int_0^1 \varphi (f)$$ 
for any Borel-measurable real function $f$, then $\varphi$ is convex.

Ps: I realize homework questions have to be tagged as such. This isn't a homework problem. I came across this question in a text book, and I thought it was interesting.

Comment: Could you give the name of the book?

Comment: I was using a random book at the school library and I didn't look at the title/author. Sadly, I'm home now.

Comment: There is an amibiguity in the question.  Does it mean "if there is any Borel-measurable function such that this inequality holds", or does it mean "If it is the case that for any Borel-measurable function, for which this inequality holds"?  It can be read either way.  If you mean what I think you mean, then merely changing "any" to "every" would disambiguate it.  "Any" is often a potentially ambiguous word.  Be careful with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can verify the [definition of convexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) directly by taking a suitable $f$. Given $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb R$ and $t \in [0,1]$, we apply the hypothesis to the *step* function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ given by
$$
f(s) = \begin{cases}
x_1, &0 \leqslant s \leqslant t,
\\ x_2, &t \lt s \leqslant 1.
\end{cases}
$$
This gives us
$$
\varphi\left(\int_0^t x_1 ds + \int_t^1 x_2 ds \right) \leqslant \int_0^t  \varphi(x_1) ds + \int_t^1 \varphi(x_2) ds
$$
$$
\implies \quad\varphi(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) \leqslant t \ \varphi(x_1) + (1-t) \ \varphi(x_2),
$$
which is what we want to prove.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So essentially, coming up with the function $f(s)$ is critical.

Comment: @Colin Yes, that is crucial. But once we are told what to show and staring at the definition of a convex function, this is not that hard, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $\varphi:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$.

Definition of convex is: For each $\alpha\in[0,1]$ and for each $x$, $y$ the inequality
$$\varphi(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y) \le \alpha \varphi(x) + (1-\alpha) \varphi(y).$$

Try to use the following measure:
$$\mu(A) = \alpha \chi_{\{x\}}(A) + (1-\alpha) \chi_{\{y\}}(A)$$
and the function $f(x)=x$.

Here $\chi_B$ denotes the [characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) of the set $B$ (a.k.a. indicator function). The measure $\mu$ is basically a convex combination of two [Dirac measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) $\delta_x$ and $\delta_y$, i.e.
$$\mu(A)=\alpha \delta_x(A)+ (1-\alpha) \delta_y (A).$$

To prove that this implies convexity it suffices to show that for any function $g$ we have
$$\int g \mathrm{d}\mu = \alpha g(x) + (1-\alpha) g(y).$$

---

EDIT: I understood the question as follows: Suppose that [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) holds for arbitrary measure and arbitray $\varphi$, $f$. Then prove convexity. Srivatsan's answer is better, since he only uses the usual (Lebesgue) measure - which was probably the original intention of the question. (Although I have a simpler function $f$...)

Comment: Is $A$ an arbitrary set?

Comment: $A$ is arbitrary subset of $[0,1]$. (I am defining the measure on $[0,1]$.) I might have misunderstood the question - I am not sure whether we can choose arbitrary measure or we should use the usual measure on $[0,1]$ only.